# Is it legal to compare date / datetime / time / timestamp / etc using comparison operators ( greater than / less than / equals ) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Can someone point me to the official MySQL documentation where it is stated that you can do comparisons like this:

```
DECLARE mydate DATE;
...
IF mydate > '2015-04-01' THEN
    ...
END IF;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean *comparisons *? Inside your procedure or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html)

When you compare a DATE, TIME, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP to a constant string with the `<, <=, =, >=, >, or BETWEEN operators`, MySQL normally converts the string to an internal long integer for faster comparison (and also for a bit more “relaxed” string checking). However, this conversion is subject to the following exceptions:

1. When you compare two columns
2. When you compare a DATE, TIME, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP column to an
   expression
3. When you use any comparison method other than those just listed,
   such as IN or STRCMP().

For those exceptions, the comparison is done by converting the objects to strings and performing a string comparison.
To be on the safe side, assume that strings are compared as strings and use the appropriate string functions if you want to compare a temporal value to a string.
The special “zero” date '0000-00-00' can be stored and retrieved as '0000-00-00'. When a '0000-00-00' date is used through Connector/ODBC, it is automatically converted to NULL because ODBC cannot handle that kind of date.
Because MySQL performs the conversions just described, the following statements work (assume that idate is a DATE column):

```
INSERT INTO t1 (idate) VALUES (19970505);
INSERT INTO t1 (idate) VALUES ('19970505');
INSERT INTO t1 (idate) VALUES ('97-05-05');
INSERT INTO t1 (idate) VALUES ('1997.05.05');
INSERT INTO t1 (idate) VALUES ('1997 05 05');
INSERT INTO t1 (idate) VALUES ('0000-00-00');

SELECT idate FROM t1 WHERE idate >= '1997-05-05';
SELECT idate FROM t1 WHERE idate >= 19970505;
SELECT MOD(idate,100) FROM t1 WHERE idate >= 19970505;
SELECT idate FROM t1 WHERE idate >= '19970505';
```